# "cin.ignore" hit enter twice to continue

Tags: c++

I have the following code in a for loop. When it goes through for the first time, it runs great. However, when it gets run again, it stops just before the cin.ignore, and I have to hit the enter key before I can type my input. Any reason why that is? Thanks.

```
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
string input;
getline(cin, input);
```

EDIT:

Here is the entire part of the code:

Note that the vector restaurants has 16 strings in it. And the function ifOddNumberOfRestaurants is the following:

```
void ifOddNumberOfRestaurants(vector<string> restaurants){

cout << "To begin the tournament, please add one more restaurant to the list: ";
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
string newRestaurant;
getline(cin, newRestaurant);

restaurants.push_back(newRestaurant);
}
```

The code with problems:

```
else if ( option == 5 ) {

        int numberRestaurants = restaurants.size();

        int evenOrOdd = numberRestaurants % 2;

        if (evenOrOdd == 1){

            ifOddNumberOfRestaurants(restaurants);

        }

        vector<string> battleRestaurants(restaurants);

        int stop = 0;

        while ( stop == 0 ){

            double half = battleRestaurants.size()/2;
            int option1 = 0;
            int option2 = 1;
            int match = 1;

            for(int i = 0; i < half; i++){

                cout << "Match " << match << "/" << half << " --- " << battleRestaurants[option1] << " *OR* " << battleRestaurants[option2] << "? ";
                match++;
                cout << "\nBEFORE IGNORE\n";
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                cout << "\nAFTER IGNORE\n";
                string winner;
                getline(cin, winner);


                if ( winner == battleRestaurants[option1]){
                    battleRestaurants.erase(battleRestaurants.begin() + option2);
                }
                else if ( winner == battleRestaurants[option2]){
                    battleRestaurants.erase(battleRestaurants.begin() + option1);
                }

                option1++;
                option2++;

                cout << "Postion of i: " << i << "\nPosition of Option 1: " << option1 << "\nPosition of Option 2: " << option2 << "\n" << endl;

                printRestaurants(battleRestaurants);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code so I can look at it all and see what the issue is.

Comment: Why are you using `cin.ignore` in the first place?

Comment: `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` means: "read from `cin` until we hit a `\n`".  If you execute this statement and there isn't any data on `cin` yet, it will wait for you to type some stuff that features a `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think your problem is that you have the cin.ignore(100, '\n'); When you do not need it remove that and your code should work ok. I tried just a little snippet of that part and it worked fine. EX: `vector restaurants;

```
int numberRestaurants = restaurants.size();

int evenOrOdd = numberRestaurants % 2;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
if (evenOrOdd == 1){
    cout << "To begin the tournament, please add one more restaurant to the list: ";
    //cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    string newRestaurant;
    getline(cin, newRestaurant);
    restaurants.push_back(newRestaurant);
   }
}
```

Remove the ignore thats why you have to push enter before it accepts anything else because it will ignore the first 100 chars or a new line whichever comes first.

Comment: I finally got it to work by ignoring the ignore on the first pass through. Now, I never run into problems with the con.ignore problem of having to hit enter twice to enter an input. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey K-Bake can you accept my answer so I can get credit for my answer. Thanks!

Comment: SORRY! Totally accepted you answer. Thanks for the help!